# Dynamically setting options for a select elements skips first element

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I've dynamically built an options array divided in two options group. These options groups are stored in a javascript array named `ogs`. The code for the same is as below:

```
var ogs = [];
for (optGroup in optionsList) {
    var og = document.createElement('optgroup');
    og.label = optGroup;
    var ops = optionsList[optGroup];
    for (op in ops) {
        var o = document.createElement('option');
        o.value = op;
        o.text = ops[op];
        og.appendChild(o);
    }
    ogs.push(og);
}
```

Now, I'm trying to add these options to 2 select elements, as below:

```
var from_el = document.getElementById('from_selector'), to_el = document.getElementById('to_selector');
for (i = 0; i < ogs.length; ++i) {
    var og = ogs[i];
    from_el.add(og);
    to_el.add(og);
}
```

However, at the end of the script, only `to_selector` has the options populated, whereas `from_selector` remains empty. The reason I'm populating the options like this is because both these select elements use select2, and any other method (such as `innerHTML`) is taking significantly longer. I've also tried putting these selectors in array and iterating over them, always the last select gets populated, whereas first select remains empty.

Comment: I've also tried adding a dynamically created select in an array along with these two selects, and iterating over them, always only the last select gets populated.

Comment: I am guessing the `add` method probably uses DOM methods such as  `appendChild` or similar, internally. You can not append _one_ node to more than one parent in the DOM - if you try, it will be _moved_ from the current location, to the new one. You need a "clone" of your `og` item here, to append that to the second list.

Comment: Yup, finally figured that out and used it. Just was about to add this as comment. Thanks!

Comment: Next time, please make a [mcve] using the `[<>]` snippet editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue. The problem was in the following lines:

```
from_el.add(og);
to_el.add(og);
```

When og was getting added to to_el, it was getting detached from from_el. The solution was to replace this with.

```
from_el.add(og);
to_el.add(og.cloneNode(true));
```